# Grab post info from radio button in Vbulletin

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <label for="rb_cpf_field6_1">
      Seller: I would like to list my equipment 
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="1" id="rb_cpf_field6_1" checked="checked" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <label for="rb_cpf_field6_2">
      Buyer: I'd like to inquire about a listing
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="2" id="rb_cpf_field6_2"  />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <label for="rb_cpf_field6_3">
      Both: I'm interested in buying and selling
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="3" id="rb_cpf_field6_3"  />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <label for="rb_cpf_field6_4">
      Other: I'm here for another purpose
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="4" id="rb_cpf_field6_4"  />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need to be able to grab the post info from these radio buttonselections (in PHP) , so I can do something like this:

if (is_a_buyer) {
do this
} else {
do something else
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check [$_POST](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) global variable.
See what happens when you do:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The value of the selected radio button should be on `$_POST['userfield[field6]']`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="something" action="check.php" method="POST">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="rb_cpf_field6_1">
            Seller: I would like to list my equipment 
        </label>
        <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="1" id="rb_cpf_field6_1" checked="checked" />
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="rb_cpf_field6_2">
            Buyer: I'd like to inquire about a listing
        </label>
        <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="2" id="rb_cpf_field6_2"  />
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="rb_cpf_field6_3">
            Both: I'm interested in buying and selling
        </label>
        <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="3" id="rb_cpf_field6_3"  />
  </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="rb_cpf_field6_4">
            Other: I'm here for another purpose
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="userfield[field6]" value="4" id="rb_cpf_field6_4"  />
  </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

That is your main code (I added the form tag, thinking that it doesn't exist already. If it does, remove them.)

Now, on `check.php` page, use this:

```
if ($_POST['userfield[field6]'] == 2 || $_POST['userfield[field6]'] == 3) {
    do this;
}
else {
    do something else;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['insertRadioButtonName']) == radioButtonValue || isset($_POST['insertOtherRadioButtonName']) == otherRadioButtonValue) {
    echo 'idk';
} else {
    echo 'something';
}
```